# Using Python to kick off Python subprocesses without delay

Tags: python, concurrency, subprocess

I want to launch multiple instances of a python script using `subprocess.call`, but the kick off script waits for each to complete. How do I prevent it from waiting from going one by one, without waiting for the previous job to complete?

```
step = 5
for n in range(5, 11, step):
    subprocess.call(["python", cwd + "/" + "subprocess.py", str(n - step), str(n)])
```

Comment: Side-note: If you just want two specific values, you could just do `for n in (5, 10):` and save the `range` call. Or better (for limited cases), `for start, end in ((0, 5), (5, 10)):`, and now you can skip the math.

Comment: Also, don't name your script `subprocess.py`; it will shadow the built-in `subprocess` module (I'm surprised this script runs; `import subprocess` with a `subprocess.py` in the current directory will import _your_ `subprocess.py`, not the module that ships with Python.

Comment: Indeed. That was renamed to illustrate. But the lesson is worth relearning, especially from @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the documented behaviour of [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) so you can't use it that way. Instead you can use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

```
import subprocess
import os.path

processes = []
step = 5
for n in range(5, 11, step):
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(['python', os.path.join(cwd, 'child.py'), str(n - step), str(n)]))

for p in processes:    # wait for the child processes to terminate, avoid zombies
    p.wait()
```

Note that it is a bad idea to name a file `subprocess.py`, especially if it is in the same directory as your main script - an `import subprocess` will import the local version, not the system version. I've renamed it to `child.py` in the above code.

It is also important that the parent process waits for the child processes. Omitting this can lead to ["zombie" processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) in Linux.

If you are using Python 3 you could investigate use of the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio) module.

Comment: Thanks. And good point regarding naming. That was actually just to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

From the `subprocess` documentation (emphasis mine):

- Run command with arguments. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.

Consider using [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead